# What do you wish Fiddler could do that it can't... or that you can't figure out how to do?

Tags: fiddler

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656424/fiddler-v2-hidden-features)'s comment, [EricLaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126229/ericlaw-msft) (the author of Fiddler) wrote:

> Fiddler has lots of interesting
>   features, but not all of them are
>   super well-documented. A related
>   question would be: "What do you wish
>   Fiddler could do that it can't... or
>   that you can't figure out how to do?"
>   – EricLaw -MSFT- Nov 2 at 2:54

Following the lead - what do you want from Fiddler that it doesn't have now (or you don't know whether it has)?

Answer (score 7):

I'd like it to be able to format and pretty-print XML and JSON request/response bodies, e.g.
so a raw:

```
<SomeElement><Nested><MoreNested>X</SomeElement></Nested></MoreNested>
```

Could be displayed as:

```
<SomeElement>
  <Nested>
    <MoreNested>X</SomeElement>
  </Nested>
</MoreNested>
```

Would be really useful when looking at our API calls.

I know it can do the XML tree view, but I'm more comfortable looking at raw markup so I can see exactly what's going on. I'd just like to look at the raw markup in a nicely formatted and coloured way!

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thanks.  The SyntaxView button offers syntax highlighting but not reformatting of XML. That ought not be too hard to add.

I believe the JSON Inspector (a 3rd party addon) will reformat your JSON for you, but I haven't tried it recently.

Comment: Format XML was added to the SyntaxView tab.

Answer (score 3):

The Inspectors tab has a WebForms button, which is very nice for checking x-www-form-urlencoded POST data, but as soon as the form is multipart/form-data (e.g. forms with file uploads), this button can't display it. Or can it?

Comment: Fiddler's WebForms inspector doesn't currently parse multipart/form-data responses. I was kinda hoping someone on the community would write a better version. :-)  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/Inspectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really a programming question... But, one feature I'd like is to be able to configure a standard set of screens on the right side.  I always use raw mode, for example, and have to reset it every time I start the app.

Another is that I would love to have it work in a mode where it snoops on the TCP conversation, rather than acting as a proxy, along the lines of tools such as IBM Page Detailer.  The problem is that browsers interact with proxies differently than they do when they're talking directly to hosts.

Comment: static function OnBoot(){ FiddlerObject.UI.ActivateRequestInspector("RAW"); FiddlerObject.UI.ActivateResponseInspector("RAW"); } // in CustomRules.js

Comment: The primary problem with "TCP snooping" is that you can no longer modify traffic, nor see HTTPS traffic. Nevertheless, I'm working on an importer for Netmon/Wireshark captures that would provide display-only functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can select which process to watch.

not only `browser` or `not-browser` option.

Comment: There's a drag-and-drop Process Filter button on the toolbar (at least in the current beta), which lets you select a window and only watch its associated process.

Comment: Alternatively, use the Filters tab and pick the process directly.

Comment: @KatieK: When he said "I hope I can" he was saying "I would like a feature that enables."

Answer (score 0):

I'd really like to increase the latency between the request header of an HTTP POST and the request body. I can see how you can increase the latency of the entire request as a whole, but not the individual packets.

Comment: See my answer to the question you just posed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363361/simulate-latency-between-packets-for-http-post-requests-with-fiddler/14364380#14364380