# Simulate latency between packets for HTTP POST requests with Fiddler

Tags: asp.net, xmlhttprequest, fiddler

I can see how I can script an overall latency in Fiddler using the ScriptEditor, using something like this:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.testsite.co.uk")) {
    oSession["request-trickle-delay"] = "500";
}
```

However, **I need to be more specific** and specify a delay **between the first packet of the request which contains the header, and the secondary packets that contain the body**.

I am trying to simulate a problem that is occurring with 0.3% of our web clients, from whom we are receiving a request header, but **a missing request body**. There is **no consistent user agent**. Various browsers and operating systems appear to be affected. All POST requests are originating from XMLHttpRequests (XHR). They look like this, and contain JSON bodies:

```
POST http://www.sitename.co.uk/folder/controller/list HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sitename.co.uk
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 245
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://www.sitename.co.uk
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://www.sitename.co.uk/folder/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: **removed**

{"bb":{"tl":{"lat":51.590527931951975,"lng":-0.636399852539089},"tr":{"lat":51.590527931951975,"lng":0.42652739355466096},"bl":{"lat":51.29736817638294,"lng":-0.636399852539089},"br":{"lat":51.29736817638294,"lng":0.42652739355466096}},"b":true}
```

I have checked the MTU size set at firewall level and it is set to 1500, which I believe to be fine.

The web servers are behind a load balancer and are running IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit. Website is running on ASP.NET MVC3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's worth mentioning that headers may be in more than one TCP/IP packet, and there's nothing that requires that the body be in a different packet than the headers. But I assume you're using the term packet loosely*

Fiddler v2.4.2.6 has a `Request-Body-Delay` session flag that would enable the delay you're looking for; set it to e.g. `5000` to delay the body by 5 seconds. (v2.4.2.6 is currently in alpha: https://fiddler2.com/dl/fiddler2alphasetup.exe)

FWIW, it's possible that the headers were sent but the POST body wasn't. That can happen in IE if you have a buggy plugin installed (see [Why is IE 10 Refusing to send POST data via jQuery $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188500/why-is-ie-10-refusing-to-send-post-data-via-jquery-ajax) for an example).

This problem can also occur if the connection is dropped. For instance, if you are attempting to do a POST in the OnBeforeUnload method, the headers may be sent but the process killed before the POST body is emitted.

Comment: Regarding number of packets used by different browsers for a HTTP POST, there is a nice run down here: http://josephscott.org/archives/2009/08/xmlhttprequest-xhr-uses-multiple-packets-for-http-post/

Comment: Delay works. Sadly, I couldn't replicate the bug by adding the delay.

Comment: @Junto: Yeah, I wouldn't expect the delay to be a problem; I think the culprits I suggest are likely the cause.

Comment: The first reason I can rule out because the issue is being seen across a wide variety of browsers. The second is possible, but the incident rate is high, and connections dropping would seem to be an isolated case. We aren't using OnBeforeUnload. This is a XHR request that is called as a map zoom is altered. These requests can be queued up though. Maybe the queuing is a problem.

Comment: Browsers can abort the XHR if the user navigates away or closes the tab. Similarly, you can't necessarily exclude #1 because it could be caused by an intermediary like an antivirus proxy service (these are becoming common).